# Attach an existing role to AWS Lambda with AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I want to attach and existing role to a lambda created using CDK
I am doing the below

```
  const role1 = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'Role', 'ARN', {
         mutable: true,
    });
 const lambda1 = new lambda.Function(this, 'lambda1', {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
        code: lambda.Code.asset('lambda/lambda1_function'),
        handler: 'lambda_function.lambda_handler',
        role:role1,
             reservedConcurrentExecutions: 1
    });
```

getting the below exception when I run cdk deploy

```
The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID:
```

If someone could help to fix this
PS: I am using typescript CDK@1.27.0

Comment: What is the trust policy for the role in question?

Comment: @Marcin It is having a generic a batch operation service entry, I dont see any thing wrt the lamda. Should i be adding lambda service in there?

Comment: If the trust policy does not allow `iam::AssumeRole` to lambda service, the role can't be used by your function.

Comment: Thankyou, This solved the issue

Comment: No problem. I will add an answer for future reference if you don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the `role` parameter documentation:

> Lambda execution role.
>
> This is the role that will be assumed by the function upon execution. It controls the permissions that the function will have. **The Role must be assumable by the 'lambda.amazonaws.com' service principal**.

this can be achieved by granting permission to lambda service:

```js
role1.grant(new iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments, the issue was incorrect trust policy in the role.

The issue was solved by adding `lambda.amazonaws.com` to the [trust policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html).